# Session Variable With Array

Tags: php, session

i want to use session variable in the code. my requirement is that when i click on "edit/Delete" button,record against the correspondence row is deleted automatically. can any one plz help me how to resolve this problem and also tell me how to use session variable.

```
`<?php
while($row = $result->fetch_array())
print("
<tr>
<td> $row[0] </td>
<td> $row[1] </td>
<td> $row[2] </td>
<td> $row[3] </td>
<td> $row[4] </td>
<td> <a href='dscm-Emp-Modification.php?ID= $row[0]'>Edit</a></td>
<td> <a href='dscm-Emp-Delete.php?DID= $row[0]'>Delete</a></td>
</tr>
");
?>`
```

i tried following codes but neither of them worked for me:

//method 1

```
while($row = $result->fetch_array())

$_SESSION['a']=$row[0];
$_SESSION['b']=$row[1];
$_SESSION['c']=$row[2];
$_SESSION['d']=$row[3];
$_SESSION['e']=$row[4];
print("
<tr>
 <td> $_SESSION[a] </td>
 <td> $_SESSION[b] </td>
 <td> $_SESSION[c] </td>
 <td> $_SESSION[d]</td>
<td> $_SESSION[e]</td>
<td> <a href='dscm-Emp-Modification.php?ID= $row[0]'>Edit</a></td>
<td> <a href='dscm-Emp-Delete.php?DID= $row[0]'>Delete</a></td>
</tr>
");
```

//method 2

```
{
for ($a=0; $a<=4; $a++){
$_SESSION['data']=$row;
print("
<tr>
    <td> $_SESSION[data] </td>
    <td> $_SESSION[data] </td>
    <td> $_SESSION[data] </td>
    <td> $_SESSION[data] </td>
    <td> $_SESSION[data] </td>
    <td> <a href='dscm-Emp-Modification.php?ID= $row[0]'>Edit</a></td>
    <td> <a href='dscm-Emp-Delete.php?DID= $row[0]'>Delete</a></td>
  </tr>
");
}
}
```

Comment: Why do you need that session? Are you sure you know what it is dedicated to? What you have stored in the session? Or you need to put something in it?

Comment: let me tell you the whole scenario that what i want to do..when i click on edit button for editing the corresponding entry it will direct me to the next page (Page2) and that entry automatically deleted from the (page1). i dn knw why it is happening.

Answer (score 0):

You need to call the `session_start()` function befor use the `$_SESSION`-Array.

Please read more about sessions in the PHP documentation [here](http://php.net/manual/en/book.session.php).

Comment: @Matze this answer does not solve the issue. You could see, Mr.M is just using session as a temporary variable in this situation.

Comment: exactly pedrouan..so plz tell what to do.??? do i need to describe my question more or is it enough??

Comment: I meam methode 1 works. In methode 2 you overwrite the last set value.

Comment: @matze when i use method 1 it generate wrong output. may i show u output??

Comment: Whats the Output?